# Execute a local file with node.js from an html button

Tags: javascript, html, linux, node.js

I want to execute a file from a button in html.
I'm on linux and don't want to use PHP.
Right now I have a server.js which calls an index.ejs where the buttons are showed, I honestly have tried several options with javascript but cannot get it work.

I'll appreciate your help with some general guidelines of what should I follow.
Thanks!

```
server_express.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        response.render('index', {
                title: 'Welcome!',
                message: 'Please press the button'
        }); }); app.listen(8080); console.log("Server listening!");

index.ejs
<!doctype html> <html lang="en">

<head> <title> <%= title %></title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var exec = require('child_process').execFile; var fun =function() {    console.log("fun() start");    exec('./home/root/prueba6', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());
    }); }

</script>
</head>

<body> <h1><%= title %></h1> <p><%= message %></p>

<button>
    Go! <script  "node funcion.js"type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        fun(); <body> "node funcion.js" <h1><%= title %></h1> <p><%= message %> </script> </button>  "node funcion.js" <a href
="fun();">CLICK</a>

<input type="button" value="Launch" onclick="fun();"/>

</body> </html>
```

NOTE: what fun() has, it does work correctly when executing it from termminal.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you already have.

Comment: [Hi, code added, thanks]

Comment: Your code is the worst tag soup I ever saw. Can you begin with correcting all the errors? In some areas, I have no idea what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to to the same thing several times in a row in several ways, and with different errors.

Answer (score 0):

This should works for local paths and web resources :

```
  <input type="button" onclick="ExecFile();"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function ExecFile() {
  WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  WshShell.Run(" file path ", 1, false);
  }

  </script>
```